# Traveling outside Luxembourg with a type D visa

Tags: visas, air-travel, schengen, long-stay-visas, luxembourg

I applied for a type D visa to work in Luxembourg.
My type D visa is still valid for 3 months but the provisional work permit expired before I entered Luxembourg.
Can I travel to Schengen areas now with only my passport and my valid type D visa, without a valid work permit, without a residence, and without registering with the city hall of Luxembourg?
If a border guard checks my documents, will I be in any breach of the law?